# Filtering dataframe by grouping on a column and checking if condition holds true for each member of a group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called df which contains two columns, one called order_id and one called article_name.

The dataframe has some faulty entries, where each and every article_name that belongs to one order is empty.

What I'm trying to do is filter out all rows which have an order_id for which every row with the same order_id has an empty string in place of the article_name.

I tried these two lines of code, neither of which seemed to work.

```
df\[df.groupby('order_id')\['article_name'\].transform('all') == ''\]

df\[df.groupby('order_id')\['article_name'\].all() == ''\]
```

I know for a fact that there are orders where every article_name is empty, however these two claim that there are none. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is `order_id` a primary key or does it have duplicate values?

Comment: Duplicate values. Each row is one item contained within an order. The order_id is identical for all products that were purchased within the same order.

Comment: @christallclear that still doesn't answer the question "What are you trying to achieve?" Are you trying to remove/delete rows with duplicate values? Or with empty values? Aggregate non-empty values so that you have a single row per order_id (and how to handle multiple article names: concat, list, etc.)? Or...?

Comment: @Dan I felt like I did a decent enough job of explaining it :( Apparently I was wrong.
Some orders are faulty and just contain empty article_names. I want to filter out all rows which have an order_id for which order_id every row that has that order_id has an empty article_name field.

So I would have to group them by their order_id and then check whether the article_name field is empty for all rows which have that order_id and then filter them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample data:

```python
from random import randint as ri
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'order_id': [ri(1,20) for _ in range(0,100)],
    'article_name':[fake.name() if ri(0,1) == 1 else '' for _ in range(0,100)]
})
df
```

###### Output:

```
    order_id    article_name
0   8           Morgan Sullivan
1   12          Brian Hogan
2   11          Tony Carrillo
... ...         ...
97  4   
98  18  
99  10          Matthew Smith

100 rows × 2 columns
```

Filter only empty ones:

```python
df[df['article_name'] == '']['order_id']
```

###### Output:

```
6      1
9     11
13     2
      ..
93    12
97     4
98    18

Name: order_id, Length: 49, dtype: int64
```

Count how many empty articles are within one particular order_id:

```python
df[df['article_name'] == ''].groupby('order_id').count()
```

###### Output:

```
            article_name
order_id    
1           4
2           2
3           1
...         ...
18          3
19          6
20          3

20 rows × 1 columns
```

Bear in mind this will only work if empty lines are `''`. It may also be `np.nan`, than `df['article_name'].isna()`.

> whether the article_name field is empty for all rows which have that order_id

```python
df['is_empty'] = df.article_name.isna()
gr_c = df.groupby('order_id').count()
gr_c[gr_c.article_name == gr_c.is_empty]
```

###### Output:

```
            article_name    is_empty
order_id        
19          4               4
```

Means only `order_id` 19 is all empty.

Comment: Not as elegant of a solution as I would have hoped for, but if it works it works. I only need to do it once, so quick and dirty is fine. I appreciate your help. :)

Comment: @christallclear we had to forecast what you want. After filling out initial answer I was not opting for elegance 

Comment: I felt like I explained it well :(